# Chained POST calls in Angular 8

Tags: angular, rxjs

I did a ton of research before posting this question, but 99.999% of the Google and StackOverflow links about chaining HTTP calls in Angular refer to GET requests. In theory, these should apply to POST requests as well, but my 2nd POST call is NOT getting executed; the call as a whole succeeds, but `companies/logo/{companyId}` is never called. My component has the following save code (where company is my object, and logo is a File reference for a company logo):

```
this.companyService.saveCompany(company, this.logo).subscribe(
  () => {
    this.companyForm.markAsPristine();
    this.snackBar.open('Company successfully saved.');
    this.router.navigate(['/companies']);
  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (err.status === 409) {
      this.snackBar.open('Company name already exists.');
    } else {
      this.snackBar.open('An error occurred on the server.');
    }

    this.isSaving = false;
  }
);
```

The call to `this.companyService.saveCompany` looks like this:

```
saveCompany(company: Company, logo?: File): Observable<number> {
  const saveCompany = company.id
    ? this.http.put<number>(`${this.baseUrl}companies`, company)
    : this.http.post<number>(`${this.baseUrl}companies`, company);

  if (logo) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('logo', logo);

    saveCompany.pipe(
      mergeMap(companyId =>
        this.http.post<number>(
          `${this.baseUrl}companies/logo/${companyId}`,
          formData
        )
      )
    );
  }

  return saveCompany;
}
```

The company is successfully saved to my database by the server code. However, the function defined in `mergeMap` is NEVER called; the break point in the Chrome Developer Tools never hits, my API is not called, and the logo isn't persisted on the server.

I'm fairly new to trying to do anything like chaining in RxJS, so I'm sure it's something obvious. But again, Google has revealed nothing so far.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated and educational. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not reassigning the pipe back to the variable. So only the first request is getting run.

I would also recommend `concatMap` here. It's the simplest way of switching to a new observable.

```js
saveCompany(company: Company, logo?: File): Observable<number> {
//<----- change from const to let
  let saveCompany = company.id
    ? this.http.put<number>(`${this.baseUrl}companies`, company)
    : this.http.post<number>(`${this.baseUrl}companies`, company);

  if (logo) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('logo', logo);

//  <--- assign piped observable back to variable
    saveCompany = saveCompany.pipe(
      concatMap(companyId =>
        this.http.post<number>(
          `${this.baseUrl}companies/logo/${companyId}`,
          formData
        )
      )
    );
  }

  return saveCompany;
}
```

#### Simplifying your returns

I generally prefer to `return` as soon as I can, which would have made the mistake clearer in this case.

```js
saveCompany(company: Company, logo?: File): Observable<number> {
  const saveCompany = company.id
    ? this.http.put<number>(`${this.baseUrl}companies`, company)
    : this.http.post<number>(`${this.baseUrl}companies`, company);

  // inverted check
  if (!logo) {
    return saveCompany;    
  }

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('logo', logo);

  return saveCompany.pipe(
    concatMap(companyId =>
      this.http.post<number>(
        `${this.baseUrl}companies/logo/${companyId}`,
        formData
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, Kurt, and sorry it took a couple of days to get back to you. This worked like a charm! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of chaining those calls you can use RxJS concatMap so your call will get executed one by one.

concatMap will not subscribe to the next Observable until the current one completes. The benefit of this is that the order in which the Observables are emitting is maintained.

check this medium article for a better understanding of [RxJS flattering strategies](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-map-mergemap-switchmap-and-concatmap-833fc1fb09ff).

Comment: Thanks, Akash! That's what I ended up doing. I appreciate the help!